# How to use Collection in loop

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Small doubt, In Update method I had int count, let say count == 4, then i am using for loop to get id, version and set. 
In this case Id,version and set values getting only the last value,  but how to get the all the values

I tried but i feel its wrong and not working, 
Created a seperate list for id, version and set,
eg: _details.imageList.Add(logoHeader.LogoID);

```
  public void Updates(AUnit _aUnit, int Id)
    {
        ImageDetails _details = new ImageDetails(_aUnit, Id);

        int count = (int) _aUnit.ReadBits(8);
        for (int i = 0; i < (int) count; i++)
        {
            _details.ID = (int) _aUnit.ReadBits(8);
            _details.Version = (int) _aUnit.ReadBits(8);
            _details.set = (int) _aUnit.ReadBits(24);
        }

        _details.Rset = _aUnit.Buffer.Skip(10).Take(_details.set).ToArray();

        //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(_details.PortrateImages.First());
        //Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        //Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);

        _details.UpdateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
        newData.Add(_details);
    }
public class ImageDetails
  {
    public ImageDetails(AUnit _au, int carouselId)
    {            
        carId = carouselId;
        _AUnit = _au;         

        _updateTime = "";
    }
    private string _updateTime;
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public int set { get; set; }
    public int carId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Rset { get; set; }
    public AUnit _AUnit { get; set; }
    public byte[] bytes { get; set; }
    public List<byte[]> dataArray = new List<byte[]>();

    public string UpdateTime
    {
        get { return _updateTime; }
        set { _updateTime = value; }
    }

    public List<byte[]> PImages
    {
        get
        {
            List<byte[]> Plogos = new List<byte[]>();
            if (carId == 2)
            {
                Plogos.Add(Rset);
            }
            return Plogos;
        }

    }
    public List<byte[]> LImages
    {
        get
        {
            List<byte[]> Llogos = new List<byte[]>();
            if (carId == 1)
            {
                Llogos.Add(Rset);
            }

            return Llogos;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `detail` an object(class) and make a list of details.

like,

```
public class Detail
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public int Version{get;set;}
   public int set{get;set;}
}
```

and make a list of detail like,

```
var Details = new List<Detail>();
```

and you could access it using the foreach loop. like,

```
foreach(var detail in Details){
    Console.log(detail.Id)
    .....
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this way,  List<LogoDetails>  obj = new List<LogoDetails>();
int uCount = (int)accessUnit.ReadBits(8);
 for (int i = 0; i < (int) uCount; i++)
  {
    Details logoDetails = new LogoDetails();
    Details.LogoID = ...
    Details.LogoVersion = ..
    Details.Offset = ...
                obj.Add(logoDetails);
            }



            foreach (LogoDetails listitem in obj)
            {
                logoHeader.ROffset = accessUnit.Buffer.Skip(10).Take(listitem.Offset).ToArray();                
            }

Comment: you could mark this as answer if it helped you @ArjunReddy

Comment: I mean i tried this way, it did not work, I am doing any mistake?

Comment: i have no idea about what you are doing since i have no idea about what you are up to...